# Unable to retrieve _id after insert in a Meteor.method call

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I can't get the return value of the inserted _id using the answers that I found on the same question here like this;

```
Meteor.call('saveDocument', value1, value2, function(error, result){
 var theIdYouWant = result;
});
```

and on the server;

```
saveDocument: function (value1, value2) {
  return MyCollection.insert({ 'value1': value1, 'valu2': value2}); 
}
```

The answer was from May 2013 so I don't know if this is no loner the correct way error and result are always undefined. However I can get it to work by keeping it on the server like this;

```
    'transactionInsert': function(currentUserId, trx_num, other_stuff){
        trxId = trx.insert ({
            "userID": currentUserId,
            "trx_num": trx_num, 
            ... other stuff ...
        });
    },
    'insertInvoiceItem': function(currentUserId, invoiceNum){
        invoiceItems.insert(
            {"userID": currentUserId,
            "invoice_num": invoiceNum,
            "trx_id": trxId}            
        );
    }
```

From the client `insertInvoiceItem` is called immediately after `transactionInsert`. My question is will `trxId` always be the correct id of the transaction even if thousands of users are using this or can another users transaction cause the id to be incorrect?

**Update:**

I was wrong, still not working. Here is where I'm at now;

```
Meteor.call('transactionInsert', Meteor.userId(), trx_num, 
    function(error, result){
        console.log(Session.get("trxId")); // p2YrLTiypiMm4tKma appears AFTER undefined in the console
        Session.set("trxId",result);
    });
console.log("trxId is " + Session.get("trxId")); // undefined
Meteor.call('insertInvoiceItem', Meteor.userId(), invoiceNum, Session.get("trxId")

Template.writeInvoice.helpers({  
    trxId: function() {
        return Session.get("trxId"); 
    }
})
```

on the server;

```
Meteor.methods({
    'transactionInsert': function(currentUserId, trx_num){
        return trx.insert ({
            "userID": currentUserId,
            "trx_num": trx_num
        })
    },
    'insertInvoiceItem': function(currentUserId, invoiceNum, trxId){
        invoiceItems.insert(
            {"userID": currentUserId,
            "invoice_num": invoiceNum,
            "trx_id": trxId}
        )
    }
})
```

Comment: Your original code looks okay to me. What happens if you `console.log(result)` **inside** of the callback? I suspect the issue you are having is that the `theIdYouWant` isn't defined **outside** of the callback. This is expected because it's an asynchronous function. See [this](https://www.discovermeteor.com/patterns/5828387) example.

Comment: Strange. The value shows in the console while the variable remains undefined. So if I use `theIdYouWant` in a template then it should work? Is there anything wrong with defining it as a global variable on the server like I'm doing now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Weldon stated, it might simply be a scope issue. Your variable doesn't exist outside your callback. Try defining it like so:

```
var id;

Meteor.call('saveDocument', value1, value2, function(error, result){
 id = result;
});

//Do stuff with the id...
```

Or if you need it inside a reactive computation (like a template) :

```
var id = new ReactiveVar(); //meteor add reactive-var

Meteor.call('saveDocument', value1, value2, function(error, result){
 id.set(result);
});

//Use id.get() where you need it
```

Comment: Tried both ways and it still comes back undefined. I can get it in the console but it's still not asynchronous.

Comment: After your update I really don't get what's happening in your code. You say your `console.log(Session.get("trxId"));` shows something in the console, but from what I see the first `Session.set()` happens AFTER... Can you maybe give us a MeteorPad or more precise console logs?

Edit: Oh wait I get it. Okay. I see what you mean, but I can't see anything wrong with your code... If you still haven't found any solution, try to do a MeteorPad for us to see the code in action.

Comment: I put up just enough code here to duplicate the issue - http://meteorpad.com/pad/RCTD7gvhDwscZebrS/Leaderboard

Comment: In your meteorpad (client.js) you are initializing `trxId` every time you enter the helper, so outside the meteor method call callback it will always be an empty string before the callback is run. I'm making another pad...


Edit: [This works](http://meteorpad.com/pad/rEDnGKN7vSmmoEwbm/Answer%20to%20Leoj%20Pyzynski). I added a helper and changed the way `trxId` is handled. Tell me if it is what you search, and if so I will edit my answer.

Comment: That's it! That is pretty close to one of the things that I tried but after setting up the helper I never actually used the helper because I didn't need that value anywhere else. So if I just put `{{getLastTrxId}}` in a hidden input or a non-displaying div then that should be the missing link.

Comment: What do you mean a hidden input? Use the helper if you need to get the `lastTrxId` reactive variable in your template (for a link or anything), else just use `lastTrxId.get()`.